# The best way in R to output a list with differing number of elements in each list item

Tags: r

I have a list of strings as follows

```
> mylist[2]
[[1]]
 [1] "BLUEFROG"      "BROWNFROG"    "TADPOLE"  

> mylist[5]
[[1]]
 [1] "POCKET"       "DELHI"     "BAT"     "OWL"   "PYTHON"    "PROGRAM"
```

Thus we can see that the number of strings differ for each list item. Hence, if I try 
    write.csv(mylist,file.csv)
I get an error. What could be the best way to output such files with differing number of elements in each list item. Is it possible to write mylist to a csv file with each list item corresponding to a row in the csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the `length` of each `list` element with the maximum `length` among the elements in the `list` so that `list` elements having less number of elements by elements will be padded with NA.  We use `lapply` to loop through the elements.  After padding the NAs, convert to a `data.frame` after `rbind`ing the `list` elements and then use `write.csv`

```
dat <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, `length<-`, 
                 max(lengths(mylist)))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
write.csv(dat, "yourfile.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

#### data

```
mylist <- list(c("BLUEFROG", "BROWNFROG", "TADPOLE"), c("POCKET", 
          "DELHI", "BAT", "OWL", "PYTHON", "PROGRAM"))
```

Comment: could you please explain  do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, `length<-`, max(lengths(mylist))))

Comment: @Abhi Added some explanation

Answer (score 2):

Best way to save such objects is to save in RData format.
try

```
save(mylist,file="myLists.Rdata")
```

if you want to read them in R you can do by

```
load("mylists.Rdata")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try creating your file and then appending your list elements to the file, one at a time:

```
file.create("file.csv")
lapply(mylist, function(x) write.table(matrix(x, nrow=1), "file.csv", sep=",", append=TRUE, quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE))
```

Though if your goal is to import back your data in R later, you should go with the `save`/ `Rdata` option.